# Помогите определить сказуемое

Tags: синтаксис

Так оно было на самом деле.
В этом предложении сказуемое "было" или "было на самом деле"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему, сказуемое было = происходило, а на самом деле=фактически (как?)- обстоятельство.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить:

1) Так оно было на самом деле. Сказуемое: **было так**. На самом деле ― обстоятельство.

Сравнить: **Он был таким на самом деле**. Сказуемое составное именное: **был таким.**

2) Это было на самом деле. Сказуемое: **было на самом деле.**

Пояснение:  "Оно было" здесь нельзя считать законченным выражением, речь идет **не о факте существования**, а о признаке.